# sed: Using a variable in sed

Tags: bash

I am writing a script that changes the paths in a file.  This is what I want to do.  If I have a file that has the string "/path/to/incorrect/location", I want to change it to "/path/to/correct/location".  I have tried using sed to do this by doing this...

`sed -i "s/$badpath/$goodpath/g" file`

Doing this though, does absolutely nothing and I cannot for the life of me figure it out.  I do need to use the variable for the bad path, but the good path can be written out (since that one never changes).  How would one do this?

MORE INFORMATION:

I am using GNU sed, so the `-i` flag is valid.

Comment: Do $badpath or $goodpath have / in them?  That would mess up the s command.  I suggest using different delimiters.

Comment: I usually fixed the variables to add \ before any / ("/" -> "\/").  Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Comment: try print out the vars to see how your substitution from `\ ` to `\/` works

Comment: I did, and they did substitute out correctly.  The answer by larsks provided a better solution than the one I tried to pursue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work for me, after fixing the delimiters:

```
$ cat sample
/path/to/incorrect/location
$ badpath="/path/to/incorrect/location"
$ goodpath="/path/to/correct/location"
$ sed -i "s|$badpath|$goodpath|" sample
$ cat sample
/path/to/correct/location
```

Comment: I actually wasn't aware that you could use different delimiters.  Thanks.